# Historic market data from Bitfinex

Tags: exchanges, api, historical-trade-data, bitfinex

I am trying to use the Bitfinex API to get historic OHLC data. I have posted a simmilar question on the main Stack Overflow page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47107106/bitfinex-data-api but I figure I might as well try here since there should be more people who are specifically focused on Bitcoin/Crypto here.

I have looked around extensively and can not find a decent API or source for Bitfinex historical data (which is surprising since they are currently the highest volume exchange)

Does any body here have (*successful) experience using the Bitfinex API for pulling historic OHLC data?

Or can someone recommend another reputable 3rd party source for getting this data?

Answer (score 2):

I have posted an answer regarding the code in the stackoverflow question, but if you just want the raw (or sample) data for either BTC/ETH/LTC from Bitfinex or HitBtc, you can head over to my website at www.cryptodatasets.com.
All the data is free, and gets updated every day.